# CSV Reader splitting at wrong delimiter Python 3.x.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

This is <del>probably</del> **definitely** my fault, but my comma separated value reader seems to be splitting on the wrong delimiter. I'm trying to make it separate time values like "3:00" into a list like `["3", "00"]` and then compare those numbers to another list the same format.

### CSV Reader:

```
    rows = []  
    self.file_name = None  
    if file == "pressure":  
        self.file_name = self.pressure_group 
    if file == "surface":  
        self.file_name = self.surface_interval  
    if file == "repetive": 
        self.file_name = self.rnt_calculator

    with open(self.file_name) as fp:  
        csvreader = csv.reader(fp)  

        for row in csvreader:  
            rows.append(row)  

    index = 0  
    for l in rows[0]:
        index += 1
        if file == "pressure":
            self.pressure_reference[index] = l

        if file == "surface":
            self.surface_reference[index] = l

        if file == "repetive":
            self.repetive_reference[index] = l

    del rows[0]
    if file == "pressure":
        self.pressure_rows = rows

    if file == "surface":
        self.surface_rows = rows

    if file == "repetive":
        self.repetive_rows = rows
```

### I then use the `self.surface_rows` as so:

```
             for row in self.surface_rows:
                print(str(time_to_find) + pressure_group)
                if row[0] == pressure_group:
                    for item in row[1]:
                        time_found = item.split(":")
                        if time_found[0] == time_to_find[0]:
                            if time_found[1] >= time_to_find[1]:
                                cprint(str(time_found) + " TIME FOUND", "red", attrs=["bold"])
                        if time_found[0] >= time_to_find[0]:
                            cprint(str(time_found) + " TIME FOUND", "cyan", attrs=["bold"])
```

`time_to_find` is taken from s and s is `s = input()` and then it is split `s.split(":")`

### What I get vs. What I want

Apparently my `time_found` is "0" and not "1:30" or "1:25" and so it can't be split anymore and nothing really changes except it's a one item list now (`["0"]`). Now I want something like `time_found` to be `"1:30"` into which it becomes `["1", "30"]`

### My CSV File

The csv file is stored in a .txt file and can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/BYe2LYnq)

```
BLANK,Z,O,N,M,L,K,J,I,H,G,F,E,D,C,B,A
Z,0:00,0:52,1:44,2:37,3:29,4:21,5:13,6:06,6:58,7:50,8:42,9:34,10:27,11:15,12:53,13:30
O,0:00,0:00,0:52,1:44,2:37,3:29,4:21,5:13,6:06,6:58,7:50,8:42,9:34,10:27,11:15,12:53
N,0:00,0:00,0:00,0:52,1:44,2:37,3:29,4:21,5:13,6:06,6:58,7:50,8:42,9:34,10:27,11:15
M,0:00,0:00,0:00,0:00,0:52,1:44,2:37,3:29,4:21,5:13,6:06,6:58,7:50,8:42,9:34,10:27
```

Comment: My csv file is like [this](https://pastebin.com/BYe2LYnq)

Comment: There's probably something else going on we can't see.  Your data looks fine to me.  https://pastebin.com/nLjG4vMX  Perhaps the code is misinterpreting the first column ('Z') because as far as I can tell it's the only one that doesn't split.

Comment: Any chance you can make an [mcve] for us - just write something that demonstrates the essence of what you are trying to do.

Comment: You have too much code here and nothing I can run. But you say "Apparently my time_found is "0" and not "1:30" " but I see `time_found = item.split(":")` which would say that time_found is a list not a string, so I'm confused. And how does this have anything to do with `csv` when you are manually doing the `split` anyway - the title of this entire thing is misleading.

Comment: Have you considered making [datetime.time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects) objects for comparison instead of splitting into lists?  It really isn't clear what you question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example of how you can split it. 
Essentially, you have to convert the strings to ints before comparing.

```
import tempfile
import csv

input_name = None
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
    input_name = f.name
    f.write("""BLANK,Z,O,N,M,L,K,J,I,H,G,F,E,D,C,B,A
Z,0:00,0:52,1:44,2:37,3:29,4:21,5:13,6:06,6:58,7:50,8:42,9:34,10:27,11:15,12:53,13:30
O,0:00,0:00,0:52,1:44,2:37,3:29,4:21,5:13,6:06,6:58,7:50,8:42,9:34,10:27,11:15,12:53
N,0:00,0:00,0:00,0:52,1:44,2:37,3:29,4:21,5:13,6:06,6:58,7:50,8:42,9:34,10:27,11:15
M,0:00,0:00,0:00,0:00,0:52,1:44,2:37,3:29,4:21,5:13,6:06,6:58,7:50,8:42,9:34,10:27""")

rows = []
with open(input_name, 'r') as fp:
    csvreader = csv.reader(fp)

    for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row)

    # ingore first row and first column, split the rest
    for row in rows[1:]:
        for col in row[1:]:
            hours, mins =  col.split(':')
            print(int(hours), int(mins))
```

This results in:

```
(0, 0)
(0, 52)
(1, 44)
(2, 37)
(3, 29)
(4, 21)
(5, 13)
(6, 6)
(6, 58)
(7, 50)
(8, 42)
(9, 34)
(10, 27)
...
```